# Broken Image links after migrating a Drupal site from Local Machine to Live Server

Tags: drupal-6

Whats the simplest way to update the paths of the images after migrating the website from local machine to a live server. Most of the times I end up updating the paths manually. I m convinced that there must be a simpler way which i m missing out on.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Define "image links". Theme images? ImageCache images? Uploaded images? There are lots of different components that display images in Drupal, and most of them should adapt fine to a server move as long as you update the site's URL in settings...

Comment: I think that there's likely something going wrong that you need to fix. I use a local server to test new modules before deploying them to a public website. I regularly update my local server with a fresh backup from the public website and the only times that any images break are when directory permissions are wrong in my local filesystem.

Comment: What URL is being used for the images that are failing to load? And what URL *should* those images have? Please give some examples.

Comment: Hi, I tried all suggestions here and elsewhere that I have found but my images are still not displaying after moving from a localhost multisite setup to single site on remote host. File system correct, folder permissions 777, sql query didn't change anything either, have cleared db caches too. Aaaaargh!...

any more suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the issue you're seeing is a result of not setting the filepath in the administration.  If you go into the administration (admin/settings/file-system) and simply save the page, you'll define the value for the filepath (which should remove the issues).

You could also set all files to use the original default (or local) directory as well via that interface.

The issue, in case you're wondering, is that the variable_get call under the hood for the filepath is dynamic based on the sites directory that you're loading the settings.php file from.  Once the value is set, it no longer resorts to the default setting and uses your value instead.

If you're physically moving the files from the relative location they're at locally vs on the server, then I'm not sure there's much of a great way around that issue.

Comment: Ok .. thanks for the reply. However I have tried changing the path using the file system in the past without much success . Though the next time I copy a single site frm the multi-site setup i have on my local machine and configure it individually on the live server would certainly try nd check it again. THanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have a multi-site setup on local machine and a single site setup on the live server which is what leads to broken images on deployment. The easiest way to fix this is to update the file path on the server using a simple SQL query.
 UPDATE files SET filepath = REPLACE(filepath, 'old/path', 'new/path');

Comment: I've encountered this problem also. Have you since then found out a more elegant way of solving this problem?

Comment: BTW this issue is fixed in Drupal 7. You no longer need to replace the path prefix as described above.

Answer (score 1):

When this broke for us, we had just migrated from an Acquia Drupal 7 install on local host to a production machine. It turned out that the server setup was just different enough that some of the pathing was wrong after the database import.

We found that doing a

```
select * from menu_router where path like '%sites/myoldpath%'
```

turned up a path for a page_callback called image_style_deliver which was invalid on the new server.

```
update menu_router set path 'sites/mynewpath/files/styles%', tab_root = 'sites/mynewpath/files/styles/%' where path like '%myoldpath%'
```

Turned out the be the solution. I didn't even have to regenerate any content. Drupal recovered immediately and generated the appropriate thumbnails in the correct folders.

Answer (score 0):

I moved a site from local dev server to remote dev server. All the images broke. Even new images I tried to upload after the move showed up as broken links. I finally figured out that my sites/DOMAIN_NAME/files folder permission had changed. That folder most be executable to web users, or else Drupal cannot access it to retrieve the files within that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it which I just did a while ago on my server is to edit the database .sql dump file using search and replace to replace the the file or url path you want from the old server to the new server. 
I migrated mu drupal site and discovered that the links were broken and this is what I did to solve the problem
1: take the site offline
2: back up your database using sql dump. Drop the old database.

3: use search and replace to edit a copy of the sql dump file and put the path to the url or files u want. I my case, I wanted to edit the url prefix of all my images links from e.g http://my.oldserver.co.uk to http://newserver.ac.uk.
4 create a new database and import the edited .sql file using the same db names, usernames and password.

1. bring back the site online and viola, your image links are working.